# ESP8266 sending GET Request and getting 408 Timeout error

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, esp8266

I am using esp8266 to send a **GET** Request but I am getting 408 Timeout error.

Here is a screenshot of my output.

[image]

Comment: I only count 60 characters, but you tell it your going to send 69.

Comment: @Gerben:  I am getting error when I trying to use "AT+CIPSEND=60"

Comment: Are you sending actual "carriage return" and "new line" characters or just a `\r\n` string? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're doing all this from the serial monitor. You can't use escape sequences like `\r` in the serial monitor entry box. Everything you enter is evaluated as a string of separate ASCII characters; `\r` is just a backslash character followed by lowercase r. To send a HTTP request, you make the serial monitor send the `\r\n` for you.

- First set the serial monitor to `BOTH NL & CR` permanently; it will serve you well for commands and HTTP requests as it appends `\r\n` to everything you send.
- Count the number of bytes in the your HTTP request, including the carriage return and newline characters. I count 61 characters in your request.
- Use this count in `AT+CIPSEND`
- Type the first line of your request, and stop right before the first `\r\n`, and click Send. Because of your setting, the monitor will now send what you typed *with* `\r\n` suffixed to it.
- Type and send each line of the request, just like you sent the first line, until you've sent the last line.
- Since there is an additional `\r\n` after the last line, you click Send again, without typing anything. And since the module requires `\r` to indicate the end of the data packet, you click Send one last time.

Hopefully, this should give you the right results.